# Looking for basic Rails3 search across multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, full-text-search

Rails 3: What are some of the simplest ways to provide a single search field that returns results (hits) across multiple columns in a table (model)? Table will, initially, be somewhat comparable to a simple product listing (name, description, manufacturer, material, year,...)

I'm aware of [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) though I've never used it personally. In doing my due diligence I'm wondering if there might be a simpler approach now with Rails 3?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/)... It's super easy to install, set up and use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on simple full-text search, but if your going down the road of Thinking Sphinx might I suggest: [Sunspot](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot).

[Adding Sunspot search to Rails in 5 minutes or less](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Adding-Sunspot-search-to-Rails-in-5-minutes-or-less)

Answer (score 0):

Some more:

[meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

[meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where)

[thinking-sphinx](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx)

[acts_at_indexed](https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [indextank.com](http://indextank.com). Super simple and awesome search solution for rails applications.